# Merge Two Sorted Lists in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, programming-challenge, comparative-review, ecmascript-6

**The task** is taken from [LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-two-sorted-lists/)

> *Merge two sorted linked lists and return it as a new **list**. The new list should be made by splicing together the nodes of the first two
> lists.*
>
> **Example 1**:
> [image]
>
> ```
> Input: l1 = [1,2,4], l2 = [1,3,4]
> Output: [1,1,2,3,4,4]
> ```
>
> **Example 2**:
>
> ```
> Input: l1 = [], l2 = [] 
> Output: []
> ```

> **Example 3**:
>
> ```
> Input: l1 = [], l2 = [0] 
> Output: [0]
> ```
>
> **Constraints**:
>
> - The number of nodes in both lists is in the range [0, 50].
> - `-100 <= Node.val <= 100`
> - Both `l1` and `l2` are sorted in **non-decreasing** order.

The following **solutions** are identical logically. They only differ in style:

**Style 1**

```
 /**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * function ListNode(val) {
 *     this.val = val;
 *     this.next = null;
 * }
 */
/**
 * @param {ListNode} l1
 * @param {ListNode} l2
 * @return {ListNode}
 */
var mergeTwoLists = function(l1, l2) {
    if (!l1) return l2;
    if (!l2) return l1;
    if (l1.val < l2.val) {
        l1.next = mergeTwoLists(l1.next, l2);
        return l1;
    }
    l2.next = mergeTwoLists(l2.next, l1);
    return l2;
};
```

**Style 2**

```
 /**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * function ListNode(val) {
 *     this.val = val;
 *     this.next = null;
 * }
 */
/**
 * @param {ListNode} l1
 * @param {ListNode} l2
 * @return {ListNode}
 */
var mergeTwoLists = function(l1, l2) {
    if (!l1 || !l2) return l1 || l2; 
    const linkThem = (smaller, greater) => {
        smaller.next = mergeTwoLists(smaller.next, greater);
        return smaller;
    };
    return l1.val < l2.val ? linkThem(l1,l2) : linkThem(l2,l1);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Looks good!

- I would say maybe the following styles would be just a bit more readable, easier to follow.
- We can also alter `l1` and `l2` with more descriptive variable names.

#### Line Counting Fallacy:

- Sometimes, Line/character countings are helpful for command line languages/scripts (`awk`, `grep`, `sed`, `regex`, etc.) or maybe [Code Golfing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf), is not a JavaScript practice though.

#### Iterative using a [Sentinel Node](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_node)

```
const mergeTwoLists = function(l1, l2) {
    const sentinel = {
        val: -1,
        next: null
    }

    let head = sentinel
    while (l1 && l2) {
        if (l1.val > l2.val) {
            head.next = l2
            l2 = l2.next
        } else {
            head.next = l1
            l1 = l1.next
        }
        
        head = head.next
    }

    head.next = l1 || l2

    return sentinel.next
}
```

---

#### Recursive

```
const mergeTwoLists = function(l1, l2) {
    if (l1 === null) {
        return l2
    }

    if (l2 === null) {
        return l1
    }

    if (l1.val < l2.val) {
        l1.next = mergeTwoLists(l1.next, l2)
        return l1

    } else {
        l2.next = mergeTwoLists(l1, l2.next)
        return l2
    }
}
```

#### Or even better that those:

```
const mergeTwoLists = function(l1, l2) {
    if (l1 === null) {
        return l2;
    }

    if (l2 === null) {
        return l1;
    }

    if (l1.val < l2.val) {
        l1.next = mergeTwoLists(l1.next, l2)
        return l1;

    } else {
        l2.next = mergeTwoLists(l1, l2.next)
        return l2;
    }
}
```

---

```
const mergeTwoLists = function(l1, l2) {
    const sentinel = {
        val: -1,
        next: null
    };

    let head = sentinel;
    while (l1 && l2) {
        if (l1.val > l2.val) {
            head.next = l2;
            l2 = l2.next;
        } else {
            head.next = l1;
            l1 = l1.next;
        }
        
        head = head.next;
    }

    head.next = l1 || l2;

    return sentinel.next;
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work at all!  What if one of the list items gets empty ? and other still have items left?

Comment: @programoholic What do you mean? They handle that case.

Comment: (I guess I don't "get" the 17:04 edit from [revision 3](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/250592/3) to [revision 4](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/250592/4).)